# Which thread calls the windows proc callback function?

Tags: c++, windows, callback

I am a bit unsure which thread calls the wndproc callback function. Is it the main thread from the application, like in the message loop or is a seperate windows thread ? The function has access to class objects and I dont want there to be any corruption of data if 2 thread happend to access the class object at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is main thread of application.

> An application's main thread starts its message loop after
>   initializing the application and creating at least one window. After
>   it is started, the message loop continues to retrieve messages from
>   the thread's message queue and to dispatch them to the appropriate
>   windows. The message loop ends when the GetMessage function removes
>   the WM_QUIT message from the message queue.

Source: [About Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Technically speaking, a window's wndproc is called in the context of the thread that created the window, which is *commonly*, but not *required* to be, the main application thread.  *Any* thread can create a window and have a message loop.

Comment: This segement seems to be more about the message loop you create rather then the callback function you give when you create a window ?